# Empty value returned by RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, restsharp

The code block below returns me a emtpy value. But when I send a request on the postman side, the data reaches me without any problems. What do you think is the problem? Could you help? Thank you.

Code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var client = new RestClient("url");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic mytoken");
var body = @"{" + "\n" +
@"    ""size"": 1," + "\n" +
@"    ""page"": 1," + "\n" +
@"    ""start_date"": ""2022-01-02""," + "\n" +
@"    ""end_date"": ""2022-01-03""" + "\n" +
@"}";
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
```

REST Return Emtpy Value

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AddJsonBody()`, Instead of `AddParameter()` with anonymous object

```
//Kindly check the type of start_date and end_date property.
var body = new { Size = 1, Page = 1, start_date="2022-01-02", end_date="2022-01-03"};
request.AddJsonBody(body);
```

[From Documentation](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#body-parameters):

`AddParameter("application/json", ..., ParameterType.RequestBody)` **won't work**, use `AddBody()` instead, or better, `AddJsonBody`

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. But this method didn't work.

Comment: @boylang78, can you please add error/stack trace here? Are you facing any issues while using this method? Please add more details

Comment: GET requests rarely work with the body. I seriously doubt the verb is correct here.

Comment: yeah, you are correct @AlexeyZimarev, that is why I asked OP about detail about errors